# How can I make my Bluetooth enabled IOT device sign a transaction so that POW and everything else can be done by another device?

Tags: transaction, signing

Is there some kind of IOTA C library just for signing transactions? The IOT device in question does not have Wifi and is too weak computationally to do POW.

I want the device itself sign the tx so that I can "prove" that the data in the transaction came from that specific device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is one: https://github.com/embedded-iota/iota-c-library
You probably want to checkout the [fork by francescolavra](https://github.com/francescolavra/iota-c-library). He fixed a lot of issues and improved the library. If you want to use it within an RTOS, you might want to [checkout the library implementation in RIOT](https://github.com/Citrullin/RIOT/tree/iota_new_implementation/examples/iota_transaction_pthread).